# Update an Object via a nested Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an API an fetch an object like this:

```
{
    "objectAttributes": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "Name": "First",
        "Comment": "First"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "Name": "Second",
        "Comment": "Second"
      }
    ]
}
```

I have a **parent** component which renders the **child** component via .map. The child component display all object properties.

Now i have to **update** each individual object property "Comment".

I'm using an input element with an **onChange** handler to make a **callback** to push the child properties to the parent.

Child callback:

```
  CommentChanged (val) {
    this.setState({ Comment: val })
    this.props.newServiceComment(this.state.Comment) // pass props to parent
  }
```

Child input form:

```
    <Input
      onChangeText={this.CommentChanged}
      ref='Comment'
      value={this.props.Comment}
    />
```

Parent callback:

```
  // push one Comment to objectAttributes
  addServiceComment (Comment) {
    this.state.objectAttributes.push(Comment)
  }
```

Parent render part:

```
  { objectAttributes.map(service =>
    <Child
      serviceKey={service.id}
      serviceName={service.Name}
      // add ServiceComment to parent
      newServiceComment={service.Comment}
    />
  )}
```

How can i assign (update) the properties to the correct object properties.

Comment: So what's your question ?

Comment: Did you assign a key to your children elements ?

Comment: Adding code could help clarify your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
            "objectAttributes": [
              {
                "id": "1",
                "Name": "First",
                "Comment": "First"
              },
              {
                "id": "2",
                "Name": "Second",
                "Comment": "Second"
              }
            ]
     }
 }
 handleChange(i, val){
  const newArray = this.state.objectAttributes;
  newArray[i].Comment = val;
  this.setState({
   objectAttributes: newArray
  })
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <div>
             {this.state.objectAttributes.map((ob, i)=>
     <div key={i}>{"Comment for "+ i+" object"} - {ob.Comment}</div>
    )}
    <h2>Change Comment value using below child components. Each input is a child.</h2>
             {this.state.objectAttributes.map((ob, i)=>
     <Child ob = {ob} handleChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} index= {i} key = {i} />
    )}
   </div>
  )
 }
}

class Child extends React.Component{
 render(){
  return(
   <div>
                Change comment form here - 
    <input type = "text" placeholder = {"change comment property of object " + this.props.index} onChange = {(e)=>this.props.handleChange(this.props.index, e.target.value)} value = {this.props.ob.Comment}/> 
   </div>
  )
 }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can try this, code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

When dynamically creating elements through an iteration with react each created element should have a unique key property. `<element key='*your key here*'>`
This allow react to make the distinction between the different elements.
You will find more information about this [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Your problem might be somewhere else but without more code it's hard to troubleshoot.